# grails/gorm messages bundle problem

Tags: grails, grails-orm

In my grails application i use GORM. I want to customize error messages for each class. Imagine i have this class:

```
class City {

    String name
    Region regiao
    District district

    static belongsTo = District

    static constraints = {
        regiao(blank: false, nullable:false)
        district(blank: false, nullable:false)
        name(blank: false, nullable:false, unique: true)
    }

    String toString(){
        name
    }
}
```

i want to customize the error messages in "messages.proprieties".

Imagine i want to make an error message for this class. the default error message for unique is the following:

```
default.not.unique.message=Property [{0}] of class [{1}] with value [{2}] must be unique
```

My error message will be something like this: ?

```
packagename.City.not.unique.message= Must be unique !
```

Please help, i cant get this to work..
Thx in advanced.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EDIT -- turns out that the answer is in the documentation.  Each constraint, in the Constraints section, has the property path to use.  So for unique its

className.propertyName.unique

but the path varies according to the specific constraint.

Answer (score 0):

ok so it is it. to make sure how message syntax is just check grails documentation, in constrains section. for each type of constrain, at the end there is the corresponding error message.

For example, go: http://grails.org/doc/latest/

The constrains type 'maxSize' error is the following:

Error Code: className.propertyName.maxSize.exceeded

Answer (score 0):

You want to customise below message.
`default.not.unique.message=Property [{0}] of class [{1}]` with value `[{2}]` must be unique

I have tried  below code it is working .

**city.name.unique.error = city name must be unique.**
or
**city.name.unique.message = city name must be unique.**